# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on raffle-sorting program

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

I have a "raffle" C++ program that I use to "draw out of a hat". I receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal when I try to use it, though. Here is the function:

```
vector<int> speedRaffle(vector<Player>players,int pNum){
    vector<int> spdtics,order;
    int ticnum,randy;
    vector<int>::iterator iter = spdtics.begin();
    for (int k=0;k<pNum;k++){
        for (int i=0; i<pNum; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<pow(players[i].speed,2); j++){
                for (int io=0; io<order.size(); io++) {
                    if(order[io]!=i){
                        spdtics.push_back(i);
                        ticnum++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        randy=random() % ticnum;
        for(int i=0;i<randy;i++){
            iter++;

        }
        order[k]=*iter; //Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". 
        iter=spdtics.begin();

    }
return order;
}
```

This function should take all of the players' speeds and square them. Then, it puts that many (the squares of speeds) "raffle tickets" into spdtics. It then randomly draws one "ticket" from spdtics, and puts the number of the player who owned the ticket into order. Then, it repeats again until all players have been drawn, not drawing the same player twice. It returns the order in which the players won.

The class Player contains an int speed. I call this function like this:

```
order=speedRaffle(players,pNum);
```

where players is vector and pNum is int. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh boy, `for (int j=0; j<pow(players[i].speed,2); j++)`... are you sure you want to call `pow(players[i].speed,2)` every single iteration? Careful with that.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? You're most probably accessing memory outside the bounds of the vectors, or dereferencing an invalid iterator.

Comment: @LihO Why should I be careful?

Comment: Your indentation needs fixing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You are trying to access element at index `k` in empty vector `order`**

It crashes because vector `order` is empty when you call `order[k] = *iter;`, you should use `push_back` function instead: `order.push_back(*iter);`.

**2. You use loop for "moving" iterator instead of simple `advance` call**

`advance(iter, randy - 1);` has same effect as this loop: `for(int i=0;i<randy;i++){ iter++; }`.

**3. You call `pow` in every single iteration**

```
for (int j=0; j<pow(players[i].speed,2); j++)
```

Note, that this would be much faster:

```
int maxspeed = pow(players[i].speed,2);
for (int j = 0; j < maxspeed; j++)
```

**4. Elements in vector can be accessed directly by using index**
You don't need any iterator at all in this case.

**5. Passing vector by value instead of passing it by reference**

```
vector<int> speedRaffle(vector<Player>players,int pNum)
```

Note, that copy of vector `players` is created every time you call this function. You don't want to do that. You also don't want to change this vector inside of function, so declaring this argument as `const` would be much better:

```
vector<int> speedRaffle(const vector<Player>& players, int pNum)
```

**6. Your code does not do what you need it to do**

*"It should take all of the players' speeds and square them. Then, it puts that many (the squares of speeds) "raffle tickets" into spdtics. It then randomly draws one "ticket" from spdtics, and puts the number of the player who owned the ticket into order. Then, it repeats again until all players have been drawn, not drawing the same player twice. It returns the order in which the players won."*

According to this, your function should look like this:

```
vector<int> speedRaffle(vector<Player>& players)
{
    // create vector of tickets:
    set<int> ticketOwners;
    vector<int> spdtics;
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
    {
        ticketOwners.insert(i);
        int maxspeed = pow(players[i].speed,2);
        for (int j = 0; j < maxspeed; j++)
        {
            spdtics.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    // draw ticket for every player:
    vector<int> order;
    while (!ticketOwners.empty())
    {
        set<int>::const_iterator to;
        int randy;
        do
        {
            randy = random() % spdtics.size();
            to = ticketOwners.find(spdtics[randy]);
        }
        while (to == ticketOwners.end());
        spdtics.erase(spdtics.begin() + randy);
        order.push_back(*to);
        ticketOwners.erase(to);
    }
    return order;
}
```

Also note that you don't need `pNum` argument if it's equal to `players.size()`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: spdlist still contains nothing

Comment: @user1188752 : Best would be if you create new question and provide more information - definition of class `Player` (what's the type of `speed` member?), your implementation of function `random()`... if people don't have enough information they will be just writing "what could possibly go wrong..." and so on. It's hard to help you like that.

Comment: `speed` is an int :P and you can see my implementation of random() and do you know how to fix your function?

Comment: I can put my whole program, if that's what you would like

Comment: YES! Finally! Cool man, thanks! :) If I could up-vote you, I would :P

Comment: @user1188752 : Problem was in your `random()` function, wasn't it? By the way you can upvote me later when you have 15+ rep :D

Comment: It was in the calling of `speedRaffle()`; `pNum` wasn't actually equal to `players.size()`... I used the `reserve()` function when initializing the vector, and that doesn't add to the size of the vector. And how would I have a problem in the `random()` function? `random()` is defined by `<math.h>`.

Comment: @user1188752 : `rand()` is in `math.h`, `random()` is your custom implementation of it I guess.